# If a Cave Fisher receives healing, does it keep its fire vulnerability?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, damage, healing

A cave fisher from Volo's Guide to Monsters has the following trait:

> Flammable Blood. If the cave fisher drops to half its hit points or fewer, it gains vulnerability to fire damage.

The trait makes it seems like the first time you reduce the cave fisher to half hit points or less, it is vulnerable to fire damage for the rest of the fight. But that could make some interpretations by RAW differ widely from what was (probably) intended, as finishing a long rest and healing to full hit points would not prevent it from being vulnerable to fire damage. Receiving healing, such as from *Cure Wounds* or a regeneration trait a cave fisher may gain from the Mournland (just an example-a table for Mournland monsters in E:RFTLW suggests adding regeneration to a monster) would also leave it vulnerable.

So, would a cave fisher reduced down to 1/2 hp and healed back up retain fire damage vulnerability, or would it be removed when they healed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### RAW, the vulnerability never goes away

The feature states:

> If the cave fisher drops to half its hit points or fewer, it gains vulnerability to fire damage.

There is no listed time or condition that ends this vulnerability, so strictly reading, it does not end, *ever*.

---

#### Ruling as above is a very strict adherence to the rules that need not be used

Such a ruling, however, makes approximately zero sense and clearly wasn't intended. At my own tables, I would rule that the fire vulnerability only exists *while* the Cave Fisher is at half its hit points or less.

There are a few ways to explain this narratively, given that their blood is flammable. I would probably just say they gain vulnerability to fire damage because their injuries have exposed their blood and healing can then undo this exposure.

Similarly, you could say that their blood is exposed *and they are coated in it* and that healing doesn't undo the exposure but that something like a bucket of water does despite them still being at less than half health. Note that the physical effects of healing and damage, are more or less completely undefined aspects of the game and are part of the narration.

There's plenty room for narrative to be added and rulings to be made.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this interpretation for me